# Citestyle exact like in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am new to LaTeX and have a problem with my cite style.

I use `biber` as backend, style is `alphabetic` and citestyle is `authoryear`.

Now my bibliography looks like this (which is just fine):

- **[FR14]**    R. Fielding und J. Reschke.Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTT-P/1.1): Semantics and Content. RFC 7231...
- **[SGG02]**  Abraham Silberschatz, Peter Baer Galvin und Greg Gagne.Ope-rating System Concepts. 6. Auflage. New York: John Wiley &Sons, Inc., 2002...

When I cite something with  `\cite{RFC7231}` it is displayed like this "Fielding und Reschke, 2014".

What I really want to see is "[FR14]", which is just the same as in the bibliography. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Remove `citestyle=authoryear`,

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried a lot of things, but never thought of removing  the citestyle! Works fine

Comment: @Guido Do you want to type up an answer, so we can mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex` offers the possibility to define separately the style used for citations (`citestyle` option), the style for bibliography (`bibstyle` option) or a common style (`style` option) to be use for both the citations end bibliography. In this case it is enough to use `style=alphabetic` (and not to include `citestyle=authoryear`).